# Problems calling a Model value from href

Tags: jsp

I have the next code in a jsp:

```
<display:table id="tipoIva" name="listaPgTipoIva"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    requestURI="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/tipoiva/consultar"
    export="true">

    <display:column title="ID" property="idTipoIva"
        media="html" class="sortable">
    </display:column>

    <display:column title="Valor %" property="valor"
        media="html" class="sortable">
    </display:column>

    <display:column title="Descripcion" property="descripcion"
        media="html" class="sortable">
    </display:column>

    <display:column title="Acciones">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="Ver Tipo de IVA"
            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/tipoiva/iniciomodificar/${idTipoIva¨}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
    </display:column>

</display:table>
```

When I run it, the variables are correctly shown in the `display:column` tags. Howewver, in the last `display:column`, I reference `${idTipoIva}` in the href attribute and it doesn't works. The value is, simply, empty.

Any help please? Why this happends and how should I call that variable?
Many thanks in advance.

PD: Sorry for the names of variables, I'm Spanish working in an Spanish team and we use Spanish names in consecuence.

Comment: Sorry, for more information:
I have a Controller which maps the url which I'm calling:
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/tipoiva/iniciomodificar/${idTipoIva}".
If I whrite it in the address bar of the browser, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution by myself (after hours of search and try-error).

To build the url use the jsp tag `c:url`. In my case, I write the href attribute this way:

```
href="<c:url value='/auth/tipoiva/iniciomodificar/${tipoIva.idTipoIva}'/>"
```